# How do I find if an element has been loaded using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, element, jquery-events

I am loading data into the flexigrid. I am trying to use JQuery selectors to make the rows clickable, but I am unable to do so. I want to know if the element has been fully loaded, how do I do that?

I want to do something like `if(element.load == true){//do this}`. I am not sure of how to check that out. Could anybody help me with this.

Ok, so I already have this div, and am binding a flexigrid to that div. I want to know if the flexigrid has been bound.

```
$("#GridLoad").flexigrid();
```

I want to know if the flexigrid has been bound, after that, I need to run a piece of code.

Using a `live()` on div `Gridload` would always be true as it is already there. :(

Comment: Are you binding the click events to your rows using either $.live() or $.delegate()?

Comment: I am binding a flexigrid to the div, I want to execute a piece of code after the flexigrid has been binded to that div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know if the element has been fully loaded?

There appears to be an `onSuccess` callback.

```
$("#GridLoad").flexigrid({
   'onSuccess': function() {
      // Do this.
   }
});
```

Otherwise, if the things you are binding are being lost when the table updates, attach the events via [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or simply capture them at the persistent ancestor element and examine [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/).

Comment: @macha No worries, lucky I found it because flexigrid is poorly documented :P

Comment: yeah it is poorly documented. I was trying to do onSelect, onClick etc, lucky to find this.

Comment: @macha I only found it because I examined the plugin's code. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use $(element).live('click', function () { // do something });

so that if it later loads it'll have the appropriate event binding.

Comment: Hello Tim, thank you for the answer, I have made an edit, please take a look at it

Answer (score -1):

you could use the callback function of jquery's load method.

like so :
`$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function() {

  alert('Load was performed.');

});`

Even if you are not using 'load' method, almost any method in jquery supports callbacks which happen after the functionality has been completed.
For example, ajax() has success and failure callbacks, animations has callbacks, etc.